# building a tree/ nested tree view using html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, tree

I have the following JSON data. I would like to build a tree/ nested tree view using the following data.

The desirable output would be as follows:

```
["carbon.agents.vagrant-ubuntu-precise-64-a.avgUpdateTime", "carbon.agents.vagrant-ubuntu-precise-64-a.cache.overflow", "carbon.agents.vagrant-ubuntu-precise-64-a.cache.queries", "carbon.agents.vagrant-ubuntu-precise-64-a.cache.queues", "carbon.agents.vagrant-ubuntu-precise-64-a.cache.size", "carbon.agents.vagrant-ubuntu-precise-64-a.committedPoints", "carbon.agents.vagrant-ubuntu-precise-64-a.cpuUsage", "carbon.agents.vagrant-ubuntu-precise-64-a.creates", "carbon.agents.vagrant-ubuntu-precise-64-a.errors", "carbon.agents.vagrant-ubuntu-precise-64-a.memUsage", "carbon.agents.vagrant-ubuntu-precise-64-a.metricsReceived", "carbon.agents.vagrant-ubuntu-precise-64-a.pointsPerUpdate", "carbon.agents.vagrant-ubuntu-precise-64-a.updateOperations", "carbon.aggregator.vagrant-ubuntu-precise-64-a.aggregateDatapointsSent", "carbon.aggregator.vagrant-ubuntu-precise-64-a.allocatedBuffers", "carbon.aggregator.vagrant-ubuntu-precise-64-a.bufferedDatapoints", "carbon.aggregator.vagrant-ubuntu-precise-64-a.cpuUsage", "carbon.aggregator.vagrant-ubuntu-precise-64-a.memUsage", "carbon.aggregator.vagrant-ubuntu-precise-64-a.metricsReceived", "stats.gauges.echo_server.throughput", "stats.gauges.logstash.host.10.0.1.8.cpu", "stats.gauges.logstash.host.10.0.1.8.memory_free", "stats.gauges.logstash.host.10.0.1.8.memory_total", "stats.gauges.logstash.host.10.0.1.8.rx_byte", "stats.gauges.logstash.host.10.0.1.8.rx_packets", "stats.gauges.logstash.host.10.0.1.8.tx_byte", "stats.gauges.logstash.host.10.0.1.8.tx_packets", "stats.gauges.logstash.host.general.request_time", "stats.gauges.logstash.host.nginx-lb0.act_conns"]
```

I would like to achieve the following output:
[image]

I am able to parse the json, How would we achieve the view as above using HTML and JS in particular the folder and nested folder tree view?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an online tool to do that. http://jsontree.com/ . You can try this to visualize you json data.

Also since you are interested in implementing a html/js solution. Try [jsTree](http://mbraak.github.io/jqTree/) jquery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tool http://codedestine.com/json-editor.html to visualize your json. It has many more features to edit and create json.